# Cannot authenticate with requests-gssapi on SPNEGO server

Tags: python, python-requests, kerberos

Im trying to access a SAS service on my company's intranet through python using requests but I cant get it to work due to authentication failure (401).

Im using python 3.7.4, requests 2.22.0 on Windows 10. So far I have tried/checked:

- `requests.get(follow_redirects=True)`
- Using `HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')`, `HTTPDigestAuth()`, `HttpNtlmAuth('user', 'pass')`
- Using `requests_kerberos.HTTPKerberosAuth()` with all possible parameter combinations, including setting `force_preemptive=True` flag and `principal=user@REALM`. I have confirmed with `klist` that multiple tickets do exist.
- Installing MIT Kerberos and using `requests_gssapi.HTTPSPNEGOAuth()`.
- Using curl command `curl -i -L -v --negotiate --user "domain\user:pswd" <protected_service_url>` in git bash, does authenticate.
- Opening the url in Internet explorer/Chrome obviously works. I do not have to input my credentials anywhere and any authentication is handled behind the scenes.
- the exchange of packages follows the basic Kerberos authentication flow: ask for protected service, receive a redirection to the authentication service, follow redirection with no authentication, get a 401 response and a `www-authenticate: Negotiate` challenge, respond with authentication ticket.
- I have checked the exchange of packages with Wireshark. Here is the critical request+response authentication part of the HTTP package from Chrome (successful):

Chrome request

```
[truncated]Authorization: Negotiate YIIIsgYGKwYBBQUCoIIIpjCC...
    GSS-API Generic Security Service Application Program Interface
        OID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.2 (SPNEGO - Simple Protected Negotiation)
        Simple Protected Negotiation
            negTokenInit
                mechTypes: 4 items
                mechToken: 6082086406092a864886f71201020201006e820853308208…
                krb5_blob: 6082086406092a864886f71201020201006e820853308208…
                    KRB5 OID: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 (KRB5 - Kerberos 5)
                    krb5_tok_id: KRB5_AP_REQ (0x0001)
                    Kerberos
```

=> Chrome response status

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

The browser then proceeds to automatically redirect to the service.

And here is the `requests_gssapi.HTTPSPNEGOAuth()` unsuccesful request:

```
 [truncated]Authorization: Negotiate YIIHQQYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggcw...
    GSS-API Generic Security Service Application Program Interface
        OID: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 (KRB5 - Kerberos 5)
        krb5_blob: 01006e8207303082072ca003020105a10302010ea2070305…
            krb5_tok_id: KRB5_AP_REQ (0x0001)
            Kerberos
```

=> response status

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized  (text/html)
```

My testing code now is:

```py
# 302 response is already handled by the first GET
r1 = session.get(url)  
    if r1.status_code != 401:
        print("Error! Server authorization failed at step 2. Expected response 401 but instead got: " + str(r1.status_code))
        return None
auth_url = r1.url
# step 2: server sends 401 and WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate header
# GSS-API (SPNEGO - Simple Protected Negotiation)
r2 = session.get(auth_url, auth=HTTPSPNEGOAuth(mutual_authentication=True))
```

Using the **requests-gssapi** library got me the closest but still authentication fails. I do not understand why. The Kerberos tickets used are the same. The only difference that I can see between the successful Chrome request and the failed python request is the `OID`. However I do not know how I can change that as it seems to be a library implementation detail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/pythongssapi/requests-gssapi/issues/41

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this. So for anyone facing a similar issue, here are my steps:

1. I used python [requests-gssapi](https://github.com/pythongssapi/requests-gssapi). This is a more recent version of [requests-kerberos](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos) and can be dropped in place.
2. However, this library didn't initially work with my authentication case. The reason was that the wrong authentication mechanism was selected:  **OID: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2** (KRB5 - Kerberos 5) instead of **OID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.2** (SPNEGO - Simple Protected Negotiation). Fortunately there was already a solution in an unaccepted [pull request](https://github.com/pythongssapi/requests-gssapi/pull/19) (as of Sept. 2019). Copy the gssapi_.py to your local install.
3. Use the following code as is also described in the pull request [updated README.rst](https://github.com/pythongssapi/requests-gssapi/blob/efa1be2951676f55bdd978e673d3b4ad3774f7d2/README.rst#explicit-mechanism):

```py
import gssapi
import requests
from requests_gssapi import HTTPSPNEGOAuth
try:
   spnego = gssapi.mechs.Mechanism.from_sasl_name("SPNEGO")
except AttributeError:
   spnego = gssapi.OID.from_int_seq("1.3.6.1.5.5.2")
gssapi_auth = HTTPSPNEGOAuth(mech=spnego)
r = requests.get("http://example.org", auth=gssapi_auth)
```

And done!